# How to use a 'gerund' for games?

Tags: gerunds, present-participles, deverbal

I read [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/sport/0/get-inspired/25054299). I know that **'non cricketing'** in various contexts such as *non-cricketing nations, non-cricketing players* has been used by many editors. I found this:

> *-ing* is a gerund, a noun formed from a verb.

In this sense, *cricket (as a verb)* became **'cricketing'**.

Now the question.  Given examples like the following:

> If Japan is a **non-cricketing** country, is there any **non-soccering** nation? **ALSO,**
>   
>  Do **non-chessing** people have low IQ?

How do we use *gerunds* when talking about **games/sports?** Or is **the game of cricket** an exception?

Comment: Yes, *cricket* as a verb is also something I'd like to have clarification on.

Comment: Putting the question aside, I don't believe that playing chess has any relation to IQ score at all. PS. I also wonder that why they use the term *a cricketing masterclass*, not *a cricket masterclass*. Must be some subtleties.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Ah, that's correct. It was just an example that came in my mind. I never meant that. :)

Comment: Then I suggest that you change the wording in question No.2, I also thought you were making a sweeping statement on people who don't play chess! Ask if one could use the expression "non-chessing (players) people" in place of *people who don't play or dislike playing chess*

Comment: @Mari-LouA. That won't serve the purpose of my question! Please re-read the question. I want to emphasize on using the *gerunds* and it has nothing to do with the facts whether they have low IQs. Also, it's a question - Do they have low IQs? The simple answer could be 'No. They have normal IQ level.'

Comment: I understand the question, and when I edited it I left that part untouched. However, No 2 is a separate question, it IS asking whether people who don't play chess are "unintelligent". It looks almost like a statement, and people will misinterpret it as being one. If I ask "Are non-cricketing countries smarter than those who are?" readers will think about the question itself and not if it is grammatically acceptable. Maybe I'm not expressing myself clearly. In any case our comments will have clarified your real intention.

Comment: @MaulikV, I believe you mean no harm in that IQ question. I've believed so from the start. Anyway, in my opinion it is quite prone to misinterpretation. How about changing it to a simpler sentence such as: *Do non-chessing people also like math?*

Comment: I had _no idea_ that **cricket** was widely used as a verb.  Man, this place is educational.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### - ing

Wikipedia has this to say on the usage of [-ing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/-ing)

> -ing is a suffix used to make one of the inflected forms of English verbs. This verb form is used as a present participle, as a gerund,
>   and sometimes as an independent noun or adjective.
>
> **Uses**
>
> The -ing form of a verb has both noun uses and adjectival (or
>   adverbial) uses. In either case it may function as a **non-finite verb**
>   (for example, by taking direct objects), or as **a pure noun** or
>   **adjective**. When it behaves as a non-finite verb, it is called a gerund
>   in the noun case, and a present participle in the adjectival or
>   adverbial case. Uses as pure noun or adjective may be called deverbal
>   uses.

Cricket is not usually considered a verb, native speakers won't normally say:"They cricket" or "he loves to cricket" but instead "they `go` cricketing", "he loves`to play` cricket" or "he loves `playing` cricket". Because cricket is already a noun,  it's unnecessary to use the *ing* form when we want to make it the subject of a sentence.

> Cricket is played in 104 countries

and  when it is the object

> He's mad about cricket

In the OP's question, *cricketing* is used as an adjective, "*cricketing nations / terms / shots*". Each of these expressions can be searched online.

**Footballing** is often heard and is a word I'm familiar with in British English, it too is used as an adjective and should be placed *before* nouns. For example, "Christiano Ronaldo - Footballing Superstar"

In the Cambridge Dictionary it is defined as; [*relating to or playing football:*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/footballing)

> It was the high point of his footballing career. 
>   A footballing country/hero

***Soccering*** exists and has earned its place in wiktionary: [verb; present participle of soccer.](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/soccering) Hence the noun, soccer, is conveniently used as a verb. Online I found several instances of the word used to tag images of children playing soccer.

> "This is my friend
>   [soccering](http://padfoot217.deviantart.com/art/Jacob-Soccering-303923371)
>   it up!"

**Golfing** is a noun, verb and an adjective. "I love golfing",  "I go golfing at the weekend" and "We went on a golfing holiday" are expressions widely used. [Non-golfing](https://www.google.com/search?q=non-golfing&rlz=1C1AFAB_en___IT446&oq=non-golfing&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2.4865j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&q=%22non-golfing%22&tbm=bks) in Google books produced a respectable 1,740 results

**Chess** is a board game, not a sport so I can't imagine it ever becoming a verb in its own right, or *chessing* even being used as an adjective. You can say someone is "a chess *star*" and that "he's playing chess later tonight". I can't think of any board game with -*ing* suffix but *possibly* [tiddlywinking](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Tiddlywinks) might work!

**Kayaking, judoing, basketballing, baseballing, cross(-)countrying, snowboarding, hockeying,** etc. all exist with the *ing* forms and can be used as present participles, as adjectives or [non-finitive verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-finite_verb).

Basically, if you want to add "ing" to any sport or team game there's nothing to stop you, native speakers have been doing exactly that for decades, likewise adding the prefix "non". Some expressions (cricketing and footballing) catch on while others don't. I have yet to hear *tennising* (?*tennissing*) or *gymnasting* but no doubt someone, somewhere, has coined these expressions and I have to admit, I would easily understand their meaning.

Comment: But is it incorrect to say *"Christiano Ronaldo is a football superstar"*?

Comment: No, of course not. Perfectly fine :)

Answer (score -1):

Cricket is a noun, not a verb.  You can't create a gerund from it.  However, you can make it work if you add "playing" to the context.  Example:  India is a cricket-playing country. The United States is not a cricket-playing country".  Notice I didn't use "non-" as the prefix as it is very awkward and makes for an ugly sentence.

Comment: The word *cricket* is an intransitive verb. And, in that context only the question came to my mind. Had it been just a *noun*, it was all clear. 'Non-cricketing nation/country' is used in many dailies from all across the world.

Comment: At some point, the verb *cricket* was **zero derived** from the noun.  Zero derivation is highly productive in English--although sometimes we pretend that it's not, at least when we're trying to speak Standard English.  But for at least some speakers, the ship has sailed on the derivation of the verb *cricket*.

Comment: @Karen927  "It's not the verbing that weirds English, it's the renounification." -- Anon.